Invariant Solutions of PDEs-Linear fokker-planck equation with an odd drift
I am currently writing my master thesis on Lie group analysis and recently I came across this infinitesimal generator:

I am trying to obtain group invariant solutions in their implicit form and so far my results are the follwing:



solutions which have been obtain from the system of characteristic equations

However in Bluman's book (bluman-anco 2002), he obtains a slightly different solution:

How is this possible? is there anyone who have stumbled across the same problem with me so far? I am trying to aply every possible transformation, however i can't obtain the same group invariant solution as Bluman.
